# aptitude search something # print only package names, no extranea?

Tags: bash, aptitude

`aptitude` (the less-user-hostile wrapper on `apt-get`, for you oldsters), searches and prints too much when it finds packages. If I only want to see package names, what type?

I suppose a clever `cut` could do it.

Comment: Look up attitude. :)

Comment: You could try `dpkg --get-selection` instead, or `dpkg -l` for a little more information. `dpkg --get-selections|sed 's/ *install$//'` will give you just the package names.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to pipe the output to any other command. You can change the output format of aptitude with the `-F` switch. To just print the package names use `-F%p`.

```
aptitude search foo -F%p
```

Comment: Absolutely the right answer. Fiddling with cut, awk etc. here makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ aptitude search mboxgrep | awk '{print $2}'
mboxgrep
mboxgrep:i386
```

Or,

```
$ aptitude search fgrep | cut -c5-35
pdfgrep                        
pdfgrep:i386
```

Comment: tx that's sick. & AFH's comment won't hurt folks who e-search into here